# defining events for html control running at server in c# page

Tags: c#, html, controls

i have a custom control which consists of html select and html inputtext

and i want to define the events for that custom control running at server in

c# page ?

i wan to write code  for that custom control click event in c# page?

can any one help me in that.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tutorials and articles please go through them:

[Creating Composite Custom Control](http://www.codersource.net/published/view/288/creating_composite_control_in_asp_net.aspx)

[Custom and User Controls (O'Reilly Programming ASP.Net)](http://oreilly.com/catalog/progaspdotnet/chapter/ch14.html)

[MSDN Article: Creating Custom ASP.Net Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy.aspx)

EDIT:- Please read [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1393327.aspx) at asp.net forums about problems with htmlselect. The `OnServerChange` event is described in details in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect.onserverchange(VS.71).aspx)

If possible please consider using ASP.net `DropDownList`.

Comment: i have created custom composite control it's functionlity is to filter the htmlselectbox based on the characters in htmlinputbox .
it works well,and when the control is applied to application ,i am not able to describe  event for onserverchange event for html selectbox in c#, and i am able to fire onclick event for that control in javascript.